Fairness Issue in Readers/Writers Problem Solution: Violation of Bounded Waiting
One basic problem with the Readers/Writers problem solution provided was that it was biased in favour of readers, i.e once a reader enters the system it allows other readers to join regardless of if a writer has been waiting indefinitely. In other words, it is violating the Bounded Waiting condition. Modify the algorithm such that this bias is removed.
semaphore rw_mutex = 1;
semaphore mutex = 1;
int read_count = 0;

Writer:
while (true) { 
    wait(mutex); 
    wait(rw_mutex); 
    // Writing is performed
    // ...
    signal(rw_mutex); 
    signal(mutex);
}

Reader:
while (true) { 
    wait(mutex); 
    read_count++; 
    if (read_count == 1) 
        wait(rw_mutex); // If a reader is the first one, wait for writer
    signal(mutex); 
    
    // Reading is performed
    // ...
    
    wait(mutex); 
    read_count--; 
    if (read_count == 0) 
        signal(rw_mutex); // If no more readers, signal writer
    signal(mutex); 
}

